# Connection request on linkdln to interviewers

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process, linkedin

Hi I had an interview and it went pretty well and later I have sent connection request to my interviewer who has also accepted my request.

So my question is was it wrong to sent connection request before the results are out?

And his accepting my request does that indicate anything?

Answer (score 2):

IMHO it doesn`t mean that you passed the interview.
Recruiters and HR professionals always try to grow their LinkedIn network to maximum possible size.